# How do I avoid the need to wait on and close some software driven from Perl?

Tags: perl, cmd

I have a folder full of script files. When I run them, a program to which they are native is opened, it does some stuff and a CSV file is generated. I wrote some code that I want to run each script file and produce a bunch of CSV files, one for each script.

What happens is the following: when my Perl application is executed, the software is launched and the first of the scripts is run successfully (a CSV file is created). However, at this step the Perl application waits for me to close the software before I continue. It does this for every script. What can I do to avoid this from happening?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Cwd;
my $dir = cwd();

opendir(DIR, $dir);
my @files= grep(/\.acs$/,readdir(DIR));

$dir=~s/\//\\/g;
chdir $dir;
foreach (@files)
{
    print "$_\n";
    system ("$_")
}
```

Comment: Is that external app prompting for input? If it's doing anything that requires user interaction, then perl's of course going to hang until that input's given.

Comment: Well, it's not so much as prompting for input. Once it's done running it needs to be closed because it just hangs with open data table and perl doesn't see that.

Comment: Give us an example of what `"$_"` might look like. Is this Windows?

Comment: @mob, yes its windows, $_ = script.acs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll want to fork and exec and waitpid - i.e. set up and run your own process and wait for it to finish on your own.

http://larc.ee.nthu.edu.tw/~cthuang/courses/ee2320/12_process.html

This isn't easy, but unfortunately, you're doing this on an OS that isn't script-friendly.  Doing this under Linux or OS X you wouldn't have any troubles like this.

You'll need to figure out if these commands are even available under Windows.  You may have to find some similar things that are available under windows if there is no posix compatibility library.

Comment: fork and exec and waitpid have been available in Windows for a long time. But it sounds like the child process won't finish (and waitpid won't return) until the OP manually closes the program.

Comment: perl doesn't ask you to "complete the program" - I'm guessing it's kicking open a cmd.exe window and you have to close the window?

Answer (score 1):

your best choice is to ask the application nicely to close itself after it is done.
for example, the cmd.exe command have parameter /C that does exactly that.

try to run the application with /?, and see if anything useful comes up.

failing that, you can use Win32::Process to create the process and then kill it after you are sure it is done. see the documentation for that.